# ToroPHP nginx php5-fpm configuration

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

Configurations nginx php5-fpm (change domain.com)

```
server {
  listen 80 default;
  server_name domain.com;

  root /var/www/domain.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.com.access_log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.com.error_log;
   index index.php;

   try_files $uri @rewrite;

  location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1;
  }   
  location ~ \.php {
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
   fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
   fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

This code not working with the root path...

Examples:

domain.com/parse/a/b --> works
domain.com/parse --> works

domain.com --> Not working

Answer (score 0):

The following should help you fix the problem:

Change `try_files $uri @rewrite` to `try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite`

Change `rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1;` to `rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;` to prevent an infinite rewrite loop.

If this does not fix it, let me know and I'll look into it further.

Comment: Side note: your last `location` block may be irrelevant for nginx, as nginx does **not** read htaccess.

Comment: Your changes don't resolve the root url ... example access only domain.com  (without any path)

Comment: Can you help me with this problem?